# Source Sans Pro webfont anti-aliasing issue

Tags: html, css, fonts

I am in a bit trouble now, because my design were accepted by the client and I've just started sitebuilding, when it came clear there is something wrong with my font set (Source Sans Pro). 
Here it is: first image is my design, second is the live page:

[image]
[image]

On the third one, which is not the proper font weight, illustrates the probem better (the red text on the bottom). It looks like the font is not anti-aliased at all, all the strokes are 1 OR 2 px width, which makes the letters 'S' or 'G' ugly as hell.

[image]

It seems something is wrong with rendering, but I can't figure it out how to fix it. On the css side, I don't use anything special, here is the relevant code:

`font-size: 13.5px;
font-weight: 900;
font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;`

Also, I am using Google Fonts, by linking it this way (using latin-ext to get Hungarian chars):

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,900&subset=latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
```

I have tried the following, without any success:

```
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.01) 0 0 1px;
```

I did some research with the following one, which made a difference, but actually it the wrong direction:

```
-webkit-text-stroke: 0.35px;
```

So I am more concerned that this is a font-related issue rather then a browser-related one, but I don't know how to start.

Anyway, I would really appreciate if someone can help with this, because other ways my client will refuse the font, and I have to start over the whole thing.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Google Chrome?

Comment: The screenshots were made in Chrome, yes. But the result is same - or even worse - in Internet Explorer 11

Comment: I've ran into this problem personally before when I designed a layout in Adobe Photoshop or Illustrator. Did you use a one of those or another software that uses font anti-aliasing techniques?

Comment: Sure, the first image shown above is a printscreen of my Photoshop file. There I used 'sharp' anti-aliasing, but except 'none', all options are much better than in the browser. Anyway, what I want is a a font which is recognizable even if the price is the 'blurry/smooth' effect.

Comment: Those were my woes as well, Photoshop tends to do fancy font smoothing even on the lowest settings. I would actually like to know of there is a solution to this as well..

Answer (score 0):

Deleting WOFF2 as the `@font-face src:` significantly improved look. For the given screenshots it's not so obvious for the bolder text but in fact it looks better. For the lighter text the difference is drastic. 
Browser: Chrome 80.

[image]